# Does the cppunit test frame have different version? if yes, then what is the latest version of it?

Tags: c++, testing, cppunit

Does the cppunit test frame have different version? if yes, then what is the latest version of it?

Comment: i am googling it but found 1.12 version but i have 1.2 version thats why i asked:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The most recent version is 1.12.1.

The project page is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/

Comment: but i have 1.2 version. is it latest one?

Comment: IMHO, i can state that **v1.2 < v1.12** .
So you don't have the latest version.
(really need to be patient and tolerant here!)

Answer (score 0):

The latest tagged version is 1.13.2 according to the project's [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CppUnit) entry.

The most recent version is available at https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit/. The development branch is actively updated. Version 1.13.2 was finalized on 2013-11-11.